# Website.com/cpanel access

Tags: cpanel

Is it possible to use  `www.website.com/username(cpanel)` instead of:

`www.website.com/cpanel`

To access the cpanel?

Please suggest an idea.

Comment: A question for ServerFault perhaps...?

Comment: Could you use www.website.com/username/cpanel instead? Parentheses in URLs are pretty unusual - why do you want to use them?

Comment: cPanel runs its own proxy so you should probably look into that - you could add some sort of special proxy handler (like webmail/cpanel/whm) that uses their username.

Answer (score 2):

Using username instead of cpanel after your domain name is not possible to access the cpanel.
B'coz the name(domain.com/**name**) other than some predefined names mean a directory inside your domain name.

Answer (score 2):

No this is not possible

But you can set redirection which will redirect www.website.com/username to www.website.com:2082 to achieve your requirements

Answer (score 1):

No,

Its not possible to access the cpanel by www.website.com/username(cpanel).

Could you please use the below links to access the cpanel.

```
www.website.com/cpanel
or
www.website.com:2083
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use your username because the username cannot be a keyword and if you have any file with same file name in your home directory, the chaos occurs. Hence, cPanel don't have the provision of the same.

```
http(s)://domainname.tld/cPanel
```

should be used.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct! You will need to use domain_name/cPanel or domain_name:2082 to access the cPanel.

You can not access cPanel directly using username. There is no such option to edit the cPanel access URL.

Answer (score 0):

**There is no way to access Cpanel by www.website.com/username(cpanel)**

You can access it by
www.website.com/cpanel

or

www.website.com:2083

or by

serverip:2083

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are actually a hosting provider, you will not have the name cpanel in your url for domain name access.

At most you will have `https://www.domainname.tld:2083` for access to `cPanel`
or `https://www.domainname.tld:2087` for access to `WHM` as `root`

if your hosting provider added `cpanel` in the url it will be an automatic redirect for you. so for example if you click on `cpanel` from your share hosting provider dashboard it may route you to `https://cpanel.domainprovider.tld:2083` or in most cases it should route you to `https://yourdomainname.tld:2083` which is a cpanel access..

Thank you hope this helps